# Tensorflow multiply 3D batch tensor with a 2D weight

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, broadcast

I've got two tensors with the shape shown below,

`batch.shape  = [?, 5, 4]` 
`weight.shape = [3, 5]`

by multiplying the weight with every element in the batch, I want to get

`result.shape = [?, 3, 4]`

what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newbatch = tf.transpose(batch,[1,0,2])
newbatch = tf.reshape(newbatch,[5,-1])
result = tf.matmul(weight,newbatch)
result = tf.reshape(result,[3,-1,4])
result = tf.transpose(result, [1,0,2])
```

Or more compactly:

```
newbatch = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(batch,[1,0,2]),[5,-1])
result = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.matmul(weight,newbatch),[3,-1,4]), [1,0,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tf.einsum("ijk,aj-> iak",batch,weight)
```

A generalized contraction between tensors of arbitrary dimension [Refer this for more information](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum)

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: To do matrix multiplication between 3D vs 2D and expected shape of the result should be matching and if he needs only multiplication then he has do broadcasting with the help of tf.expand

Comment: Then why didn't you say so? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer